# How to execute javascript in external HTML/SVG file in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, svg

I have an SVG file that defines some of its styles and `<defs>` dynamically with JavaScript.

I'm using said SVG file inside of an HTML file.

- If I open the SVG file on its own, its JavaScript gets executed.
- If, using jQuery, I include the SVG file into the HTML file via AJAX, (appending the SVG to the HTML document) then the SVG's JavaScript gets executed too.
- However, **using pure JavaScript: if I include the SVG file into the HTML file via AJAX** (appending the SVG to the HTML document) **then the SVG's JavaScript does NOT get executed**.

I'm trying to understand and fix the behavior.

As an MCVE:

`ajax-callee.svg`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.1"
    baseProfile="full"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    >
    <script><![CDATA[

    console.log( 'ajax-callee.svg › script tag' );

    /** When the document is ready, this self-executing function will be run. **/
    (function() {

        console.log( 'ajax-callee.svg › script tag › self-executing function' );

    })();   /* END (anonymous function) */

    ]]></script>
</svg>
```

`ajax-caller-jquery-withSVG.html` (works fine):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

    <p>(Check out the console.)</p>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "ajax-callee.svg",
            dataType: "html"
        }).done(function( html ) {
            /** Loading the external file is not enough to have, it has to be written to the doc too for the JS to be run. **/
                $( "body" ).append( html );
        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`ajax-caller-pureJS-withSVG-notworking.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

    <p>(Check out the console.)</p>

<script>

    /** AJAX CALLER **/

    /** When the document is ready, this self-executing function will be run. **/
    (function() {

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

        ajax.open("POST", "ajax-callee.svg", true);
        ajax.send();

        /**
         * Append the external SVG to this file.
         * Gets appended okay…
         * …but its JavaScript won't get executed.
         */
        ajax.onload = function(e) {

            /** Parse the response and append it **/
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var ajaxdoc = parser.parseFromString( ajax.responseText, "image/svg+xml" );
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild( ajaxdoc.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0] );

        }

    })();   /* END (anonymous function) */

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

- What does jQuery does differently that leads to the JavaScript being executed?
- What can I do to get the included's SVG JS to be run?
- Anything to beware of?

FYI, I'm trying with SVG but in my tests the behavior was the same when using HTML files for the *callee*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the HTML spec scripts that are parsed using DOMParser are not executed
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-processing-noscript

> The definition of scripting is disabled means that, amongst others, the following scripts will not execute: scripts in XMLHttpRequest's responseXML documents, scripts in DOMParser-created documents, scripts in documents created by XSLTProcessor's transformToDocument feature, and scripts that are first inserted by a script into a Document that was created using the createDocument() API. [XHR] [DOMPARSING] [XSLTP] [DOM]

Looks like jQuery is taking the text content and creating a new script tag and appending it to the document.

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js

```
DOMEval( node.textContent.replace( rcleanScript, "" ), doc, node );

function DOMEval( code, doc, node ) {
    doc = doc || document;
    var i,
        script = doc.createElement( "script" );

    script.text = code;
    if ( node ) {
        for ( i in preservedScriptAttributes ) {
            if ( node[ i ] ) {
                script[ i ] = node[ i ];
            }
        }
    }
    doc.head.appendChild( script ).parentNode.removeChild( script );
}
```

So for your code you could do the same:

```
ajaxdoc.querySelectorAll("script").forEach((scriptElement) => {
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.text = scriptElement.textContent;
    document.head.appendChild(script)
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this was most useful and the background info is insightful. I'll answer my own question too to add some handy developments.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question to add some practical details to Professor's Allman's answer.

Things to keep in mind in this context:

- In practice, the SVG's JavaScript logic will most likely depend on the SVG's content. So add the SVG before trying to execute its script.
- Adding the SVG to the document via `.appendChild()` technically moves the node. So, in my example, `ajaxdoc.querySelectorAll("script")` would be `undefined` after insert. So we'll want to make sure we look for it from the right node.
- We'll want to keep things clean and avoid duplicate script tags.
- In the original SVG, we'll want to be careful about our assumptions. e.g.: the SVG might contain a stylesheet, but not the HTML document that will run the code.

Or:

```
ajax.onload = function(e) {
    /** Parse the response **/
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var ajaxdoc = parser.parseFromString( ajax.responseText, "image/svg+xml" );


    /** Append the SVG **/
    var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild( ajaxdoc.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0] )


    /** Execute the SVG's script **/
    svg.querySelectorAll("script").forEach((scriptElement) => {
        let script = document.createElement("script");
        script.text = scriptElement.textContent;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        scriptElement.remove(); // avoid duplicate script tags
    });
```